# How to call a variable from another function in tkinter python and raspberry pi?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

We are creating a prototype of a ventilator and we want to display the options and results of the users to the monitor of raspberry pi. The problem is, we cannot call a data of the checkbox under different function. Below is our code and we are trying to call the variable of the checkbox under the `start_button()` but calling it under different function.

We are receiving an error such as the var1 is not defined, or when we declare it as global, it was not showing its real value.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import bmpsensor
import time
import threading
import os
import max30100
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from sim800l import SIM800L
sim800l=SIM800L('/dev/serial0')

global window
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('900x600')
window.title('MCU-BASED VENTILATOR')


def start_button():
    global window1
    window1 = tkinter.Tk()
    window1.geometry('900x600')
    window1.title('SETTINGS')
    label2=Label(window1, text='CHOOSE THE SENSORS TO USE', font=('Montserrat 35 bold'))
    label2.pack(pady=50)
    global var1, var2, IntVar
    var1 = tkinter.IntVar()
    var2 = tkinter.IntVar()
    check=tkinter.Checkbutton(window1, text = "PULSE OXIMETER", font=('Montserrat 20'), variable=var1).pack(side=TOP)
    check1=tkinter.Checkbutton(window1, text = "ELECTROCARDIOGRAM (ECG)", font=('Montserrat 20'), variable=var2).pack(side=TOP)
    bt1=tkinter.Button(window1, text = "NEXT", bg = "sky blue" , fg = "white",height=2, width = 10, command = next_button)
    bt1.place(x=700, y=500)
    window.withdraw()


def next_button():
    global window2
    window1.withdraw()
    window2 = tkinter.Tk()
    window2.geometry('900x600')
    window2.title('SETTINGS')
    label3=Label(window2, text="SELECT VENTILATOR'S I:E RATIO", font=('Montserrat 35 bold'))
    label3.pack(pady=50)
    bt=tkinter.Button(window2, text = "10 BPM", bg = "sky blue" , fg = "white",height=2, width = 25)
    bt.pack(side = TOP, pady=10)
    bt1=tkinter.Button(window2, text = "20 BPM", bg = "sky blue" , fg = "white",height=2, width = 25)
    bt1.pack(side = TOP, pady=10)
    bt2=tkinter.Button(window2, text = "30 BPM", bg = "sky blue" , fg = "white",height=2, width = 25)
    bt2.pack(side = TOP, pady=10)
    bt3=tkinter.Button(window2, text = "NEXT", bg = "sky blue" , fg = "white",height=2, width = 10, command = next1_button)
    bt3.place(x=700, y=500)
    
def next1_button():
    global window3
    window2.withdraw()
    window3 = tkinter.Tk()
    window3.geometry('900x600')
    window3.title('SETTINGS')
    label4=Label(window3, text="SUMMARY", font=('Montserrat 35 bold'))
    label4.pack(pady=50)
    label5=Label(window3, text="PULSE OXIMETER:", font=('Montserrat 15 bold'))
    label5.pack(pady=50)
    if (var1 == 1):
        label20=Label(window3, text="ON").pack()
    else:
        label21=Label(window3, text="OFF").pack()
        
    bt3=tkinter.Button(window3, text = "START", bg = "sky blue" , fg = "white",height=2, width = 10, command = results_button)
    bt3.place(x=700, y=500)
    
def results_button():
    global window4
    window3.withdraw()
    window4 = tkinter.Tk()
    window4.geometry('900x600')
    window4.title('SETTINGS')
    label4=Label(window4, text="RESULTS", font=('Montserrat 35 bold'))
    label4.pack(pady=50)
   

    
"""1st page"""
label1=Label(window, text='WELCOME', font=('Montserrat 35 bold'))
label1.pack(pady=50)
label1a=Label(window, text='MCU-Based Controlled Oxygen Ventilator \n with GSM Alert and Monitoring System', font=('Montserrat', 15))
label1a.pack()
bt=tkinter.Button(window, text = "START", bg = "sky blue" , fg = "white",height=2, width = 10, command = start_button)
bt.pack(side = TOP, pady=100)



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add both var1, var2 on top of start_button() function.

Comment: the first 2 lines of code:  `import tkinter` and `from tkinter import *` do the same thing...  using `*` is considered to be poor practice by many.

Comment: Use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` for child windows.

Comment: You haver too many duplicates. You can used one tk for whole script.

Comment: I changed all tk to toplevel. I also tried to add var1 and var2 on top of the start_button() but once I called it on another function, it does not reflect its real value, like for example, if var1=1, it must print "ON" on the other hand, it always prints "OFF"